# Subalgebra of algebra of derivations

Tags: abstract-algebra

> I would like to prove that a finitely generated subalgebra of the algebra of derivations of a finite algebra over the ring $F$ is finite over $F$.

I have absolutely no idea how can I do it.

Comment: Just to be clear, by finite, you mean finitely generated as an $F$-module, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm think so.

Comment: You think so? But you are the one asking about this. You need to know what you are asking about, or there is no chance for people to help you.

Comment: Just poor knowledge of English. You are right, finite as finitely generated as an F-module.